# Dajax/Dajaxice the Js call returns "Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined"

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajaxice, dajax

I installed and followed all the [procedures](http://django-dajax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#) to setup a basic example using Dajax and Dajaxice inside Django.
The js sources are correctly included and the Dajax and Dajaxice objects exist (I can test within the browser console). I've looked around but it seems I can not find a solution for this: when I fire my function from js like so:

```
<button onclick="Dajaxice.projectName.appName(Dajax.process);">Click here!</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="Dajaxice.appName(Dajax.process);">Click here!</button>
```

I always get back in the browser js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectName' of undefined
```

or

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appname' of undefined
```

Everything is set up in the ajax.py and urls.py. The documentation does not help much with my problem.

Comment: sorry for off-topic
I walked the same way as you and initially tried to harness Dajax. After some tries and errors, I returned to the basics, and started to work with ajax directly since. I'm so happy ;) and don't have any headache at all.
Nothing wrong about Dajax authors, just direct ajax is rather simple.